# how to throw and handle custom exception from unit test

Tags: c#, unit-testing, exception

I have custom exception-->

```
    public CustomException(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context)
        : base(info, context)
    {  }
```

i am writing a unit test for it-->

```
    [TestMethod]
    [ExpectedException(typeof(CustomException))]
    public void TestCustomException()
    {
        throw new CustomException(info:SerializationInfo, context:StreamingContext);
    }
```

the error shows as SerializationInfo & StreamingContext is type and not valid for the given context.

could you please let me know what should be the correct way to throw the custom exception from the unit test ?

Comment: Not following your syntax.  what are `info:SerializationInfo` and `context:StreamingContext` supposed to represent?  Where do they come from?

Comment: i wanted to throw the custom exception but not sure what should be the correct syntax, i just thought of trying to mention what i am using in the CustomException(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context)

Comment: Create a new `SerializationInfo` and a new `StreamingContext` and use those as parameters

Comment: Not sure what you are actually achieving though, of course it throws it. Perhaps you want to test the data in the exception?

Comment: it is to satisfy code coverage for that customexception method

Answer (score -1):

Here is what is did run unit test:

```
[TestMethod]
[ExpectedException(typeof(CustomException))]
public void TestCustomException()
{
        SerializationInfo info = new SerializationInfo(typeof(CustomException), new FormatterConverter());
        info.AddValue("ClassName", string.Empty);
        info.AddValue("ExceptionMethod", string.Empty);
        info.AddValue("HResult", 1);
        info.AddValue("Source", string.Empty);
        info.AddValue("Message", string.Empty);
        info.AddValue("InnerException", new ArgumentException());
        info.AddValue("HelpURL", string.Empty);
        info.AddValue("StackTraceString", string.Empty);
        info.AddValue("RemoteStackTraceString", string.Empty);
        info.AddValue("RemoteStackIndex", 0);    
        StreamingContext context = new StreamingContext()
        throw new CustomException(info,context);
}
```

Comment: So your question actually was _"how to instantiate a SerializationInfo so I can pass it to my exception's constructor"_, and you have written some code that seems to do so. What requirements does this code fulfill? Is this the minimum needed to make it compile and run? What does this test accomplish?